# Group Number in AFP Viewer TLE Browser not increasing sequentially after AFP merge

Tags: java, afp

I have merged three AFP files using java utility which reads bytes from file and writes to Output Stream using `FileOutputStream` Java class. 
The merged AFP file looks good but when TLE(Tag Logical Element) information is checked in Compulsive Code `AFPViewer`(in TLE Browser) after opening AFP file, the Group Number remains same for all merged files to GRP:PGP00001

Please let me know how can I merge the files so that GRP number should start increasing sequentially after AFP merge. 
Result should be GRP:PGP00001, GRP:PGP00002 and GRP:PGP00003

Used following code for merging each AFP file generated using Apache FOP XSL-FO:

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

// Get the size of the file
long length = file.length();

// Create the byte array to hold the data
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

// Read in the bytes
int offset = 0;
int numRead = 0;
while (offset < bytes.length
       && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
    offset += numRead;
}

// Ensure all the bytes have been read in
if (offset < bytes.length) {
    throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
}

// Close the input stream and return bytes
is.close();
return bytes;
}
```

Main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\dev\\harry\\ETCC_data\\output.afp");
    byte[] bytes1 = getBytesFromFile(new File(filePath1));
    byte[] bytes2 = getBytesFromFile(new File(filePath2));
    fos.write(bytes1);
    fos.write(bytes2);
    fos.flush(); 
    fos.close(); 
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex) { System.out.println("FileNotFoundException : " + ex); }
catch(IOException ioe) { System.out.println("IOException : " + ioe); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

afplib does have some sample code on how to correctly merge several AFP files into one:

https://github.com/yan74/afplib/wiki/Samples#afpcombinejava
https://github.com/yan74/afplib/blob/master/org.afplib.samples/src/main/java/org/afplib/samples/AfpCombine.java

```
package org.afplib.samples;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.Test;

public class AfpCombineTest {

    @Test
    public void testRun() throws IOException {
        new File("tmp").mkdirs();
        AfpCombine combine = new AfpCombine("tmp/out.afp", new String[] { "testdata/start.afp", "testdata/start.afp" , "testdata/ende.afp" , "testdata/ende.afp"});
        combine.run();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Binary merge does not work well for AFP/MO:DCA files.

Along with the resource names, there can be plenty of issues.
Just for one, shared resources (`BRG`…`ERG`), which usually prepend the document (e.g., they sit before `BDT`…`EDT`) must always remain before.
Also, there can be clashes among mapped color identifiers, image formats, and many more.

In fact, it appears that plain binary merge works only for the simplest documents. In other words, almost never.

In order to merge several documents properly, one must dig into the document structure and adjust all necessary Structured Fields.

There are several Java libraries for AFP, like [afplib](https://github.com/yan74/afplib).

I've also seen those who employ Apache FOP's [AFP module](http://afp-renderer.sourceforge.net/api/overview-summary.html) for this purpose, albeit it mostly targets *creating* the documents, not *editing* those.

Answer (score 0):

Merging AFP files is not just such simple as
cat afp1 afp2 > out
We need to make sure that, we follow MODCA structure after combining two files.
All your resources in 1 st afp file and second afp file in one BRG-ERG group and all your data pages are should be in one BDT-EDT group. 
Below is the flow.

[image: Merge AFP Files]

After merging like above, there will be an issue with duplicate resources.
Say AFP 1 uses a codefont CO10001 which is Arial 10
AFP 2 uses a codefont CO10001 (same name)which is Helvetica 10

Printer will pick the first font which is available, hence you will not get expected print.

Make sure when you're merging, no resources should have same name with different properties and remove duplicate resources if any, which is a good practice.

Answering you're, you can have counter variable in you're program and when ever you encounter a BNG record, you can update the existing record by updating it or you can write you're own BNG record.